# Flexbox wrap and overflow behaviour different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a form, where each field has a separate label and an input box, but it behaves differently on Firefox and Chrome. This is built with React.

Chrome, works as intended—
[image]

and in Firefox, broken—
[image]

Here’s the markup—

```html
<!-- The React template -->
<FormUnit>
    <InputField />
    <InputLabel value="Company name" />
</FormUnit>

<!-- which becomes: -->
<div class="ff-form-unit">
    <input class="ff-input">
    <label class="ff-input-label">Company name</label>
</div>
```

and the CSS—

```
/* The parent unit */ 
.ff-form-unit {
    display        : flex;
    position       : relative;
    width          : 100%;
    flex-direction : column;
    align-items    : center;
    flex-wrap      : wrap;
}

/* The text field */
.ff-input {
    position : relative;
    width    : 100%;
    flex     : 1 1 auto;
}

/* The label for the field */
.ff-form-unit > label, {
    position   : relative;
    display    : flex;
    flex       : 1 0 100%;
    align-self : flex-start;
    order      : -1;
}
```

How can I fix this? What exactly is causing this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you tried to report it to Firefox guys?

Comment: Hmm, no, not yet. Let’s see if someone else is able to come up with a solution.

Comment: can you share the final HTML code? there is probably some fieldset generated. If so I know the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif Added.

Comment: it seems fine on FF: https://jsfiddle.net/a3y2ztjx/ you have for sure more CSS involved

Comment: Hmm, the `form` parent has a `display:flex; flex-direction:column` property. Disabling that solves this problem. But how is that affecting this?